# Cannot connect to repository Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, software-center, update-manager, repository

Freshly installed ubuntu. Did the normal installation and unchecked the third party apps.

Now when I try to install apps using the repository or update it I get this error.

```
sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease               
Err:2 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                      
  Cannot initiate the connection to in.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2403:8940:ffff::f). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (103.97.84.254), connection timed out
Err:3 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease
  Cannot initiate the connection to in.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2403:8940:ffff::f). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
Err:4 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
  Cannot initiate the connection to in.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2403:8940:ffff::f). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/InRelease  Cannot initiate the connection to in.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2403:8940:ffff::f). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (103.97.84.254), connection timed out
W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/InRelease  Cannot initiate the connection to in.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2403:8940:ffff::f). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-backports/InRelease  Cannot initiate the connection to in.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2403:8940:ffff::f). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I also have only these in the Software and Update setting. Please help!

[image]